# Linking Python static library

Tags: python, c++, dll

I have a task: I have some python script, and it should be used in a DLL. At the same time to minimize the amount of output files (preferably to a one dll).

Python script embded to project resources and is using by Python / C API. The next step, I would like to integrate python interpreter into my dll.

For this:

- I download the source code of Python 2.7.11 from the official site
- Select one project - pythoncore
- Configuration Type changed from DLL (dynamic link library) to LIB (static library)
- Link ready python27.lib to my Project(~15Mb!)

As far as I know, when I compiling my project, statica library must export code to my DLL. Accordingly, this LIB file is completely self-sufficient (as I understand).

But when I compiling my project, I get the errors like this:

> Error 3 error LNK2019: unresolved external reference to the symbol
>   __imp__Py_Initialize In function _main E: \ 7zip \ myprogtamm \ myprogtamm \ main.obj

The source code of this function is present in the project - pythoncore. Both projects - X86

What could be the reason of this errors?